# Make SOAP request in Go

Tags: go

I've seen several other similar questions on Stack Overflow, but they're fairly old / potentially outdated so I'm wondering if there's any new packages or methods for making SOAP requests in Go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think there are none.

To begin with, there are two documents describing soap—the so-called "SOAP Note" which is officially not a standard but is widely referred to as "SOAP 1.0", and another one, which is *the* standard and is commonly referred to as SOAP 1.1. They are not compatible even though they look superficially the same.

On the other hand, SOAP itself—as XML encoding of what
the client sends, and what the server responds with—is simple,
and in fact crafting a simple SOAP wrapper (to make client calls) and
unwrapper (to decapsulate server's responses) is simple.

I'd like to stress this: both SOAP standards do not actually deal with
HTTP as SOAP is explicitly defined to be transport-agnostic
(it hence suffers from the same problem the ReST paradigm does: everyone
thinks it's about HTTP), and the Go's standard library features excellent
support for HTTP, so the SOAP encoding/decoding layer appears to be rather
thin.

With these considerations, I, personally, did not even bother to start
depending on a 3rd-party package for SOAP in each of the cases I needed to
call something over SOAP and wrote the necessary code myself;
I've just checked that the last time I needed
to do SOAP 1.2 calls, the SOAP encoder/decoder ended up being 171 lines
of Go code (excluding tests).

So I'd say just roll your own.

Note though that it's all that simple only if your server does not require
something awry to use—for instance that dreaded WS-Security extension
which requires special formatting of XML to be sent,
calculating cryptographic hashes over it, digitally signing them
and all such stuff; there's just nothing to handle this in Go as of yet.

The same applies so WSDL specs or XSD schemas.
IIUC, there presently is no tools of sufficient quality which would generate
type hierarchies and SOAP endpoint client stubs for you given a WSDL
document or an XSD schema.